# Rotate a Rigidbody to align with an orientation

Tags: unity-game-engine, math

I'm currently setting the rotation of a player object so that it "stands up" relative to the spheroid the user stands on.

However, that will break Rigidbody physics.

I already have the direction of gravity as a Quaternion, how can add torque to the Rigidbody so that it aligns with that direction?

Here's [my code on Github](https://github.com/Punchcards/Sphere/blob/main/Assets/TileManager.cs#L314), which does allow the player to move around the surface of the planet.

I have tried various approaches using AddTorque and Vector3.Cross, but they have all only ended in the Rigidbody spinning wildly.

Comment: You are right in saying that you will need to use add torque. Check out [this Unity Answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1194362/apply-torque-to-align-rigidbody-to-a-specific-angl-2.html) post. If you are still unable to get an answer from this post I can make a more formal answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `transform` whenever a `Rigidbody` is involved rather first calculate the needed final `Quaternion` ad then apply it using [`theRigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) which does not break the physics.

The same also accounts to the position where you should rather use [`theRigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html).

Both should be used in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) so

- either move the entire code from `Update` to `FixedUpdate`
- or split the input and the physics and do your API stuff in `Update`, store the relevant values into fields but apply anything related to the Rigidbod transformations reactive in `FixedUpdate`.

Your code is quite complex so I will only give an example as a pseudo code and hope you can take it from there

So instead of doing e.g.

```
private void Update ()
{
    player.transform.position = XYZ;

    // Applies a world space rotation
    player.transform.rotation = XYZW;
    // Adds a relative rotation in local space
    player.transform.Rotate(x,y,z);
}
```

You would rather do something like

```
[SerializeField] Rigidbody playerRb;

private Vector3 targetPosition;
private Quaternion targetRotation;

private void Awake ()
{
    if(!playerRb) playerRb = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update ()
{
    targetPosition = XYZ;

    targetRotation = XYZW * Quaternion.Euler(x,y,z);
}

private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    playerRb.MovePosition(targetPosition);
    playerRb.MoveRotation(targetRotation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've implemented the use of MoveRotation and MovePosition, which does seem to keep the right rotation, but I do get some weird behaviour when I collide with another Rigidbody, I've made a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMoQ7f-JWZ0

For one thing, the capsule seems able to push through the cube, and once you've collided once, you're stuck moving slightly forwards or backwards.